# Crystal Report loop in a formula

Tags: loops, crystal-reports

I have this in a formula:
If "03/07" <= {@ReportDate} and  {scregion.ion_desc}  = "01 Bismarck & Subdlr" and {sccoa.coa_desc} = "Exchange Credits" then 300 else
If "03/10" <= {@ReportDate} and  {scregion.ion_desc}  = "01 Bismarck & Subdlr" and {sccoa.coa_desc} = "Exchange Credits" then 733 else
If "03/20" <= {@ReportDate} and  {scregion.ion_desc}  = "01 Bismarck & Subdlr" and {sccoa.coa_desc} = "Exchange Credits" then 1012 else

Instead of an if statement, can someone help me with a loop?  So that the formula will look at the date and return the correct value?

Thanks,
Mathew

Comment: Place the formula field in the `DETAIL` Section ,it will work like a loop

Comment: When I place the formula in the detail section it returns the first value in the if statement.  It does not continue to evaluate and replace that value if the next one is true.

Comment: Post your report structure and also the output you are getting and the expected output

Comment: I decided to stick with sub reports. I was trying to use a formula as I do with some data because it's faster.

Comment: I decided to stick with sub reports. I was trying to use a formula as I do with some data because it's faster.  I'm not sure what to post for you to look at.  My original post is part of the formula.  The report date is 5/4, When I place the formula, it returns 300, but I would like it to return 1012 which is the last if statement.  I was hoping it would keep evaluating each statement and because each one is true it would return the last one.